# How to show and hide password in Tkinter with the help of button?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a show and hide button in Tkinter which on click make the password visible and on clicking hide it will hide the password.
First of all, I have used an Entry widget to enter the password and with the help of (show="*"),I have made the password to be entered in * format which hides the password. But if I want to check what I have entered for that I need a show button and then again hide it after confirming.

Comment: Use `show=''` to show the password.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code, or links to actual code. Take the time to [edit]  your question to include a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `show=''` to show the password and `show='*'` to hide the password:

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_password():
    if passwd_entry.cget('show') == '':
        passwd_entry.config(show='*')
        toggle_btn.config(text='Show Password')
    else:
        passwd_entry.config(show='')
        toggle_btn.config(text='Hide Password')

root = tk.Tk()

passwd_entry = tk.Entry(root, show='*', width=20)
passwd_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

toggle_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Show Password', width=15, command=toggle_password)
toggle_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```